# Is it possible to use a python virtual environment configured in Ubuntu on Windows in VS Code on Windows?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, virtual-environment

When on pure Ubuntu, VS Code would use an activated python virtual environment as the current development environment if I launched it with `code ./` from the command line.

On Windows 10 I set up WSL with Ubuntu starting in hyper.js terminal using zsh. When I start VS Code in a similar way and with activated virtual environment this does not work because VS Code runs in the Windows environment.

Is there any way to get VS Code recognize and use the activated virtual environment? If not, is there another way to make Visual Studio Code on Windows use a virtual environment configured within Ubuntu for Windows?

Comment: It's not clear what python/venvs have to do with this. Getting `code` to execute ought to work iff vscode is installed and on your path, which is a separate problem from virtual environments.

Comment: I see the fuzzyness within my explanations. In fact my focus was on how to use a python virtual environment configured in within Ubuntu on Windows in Visual Studio Code. I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked with my installation of WSL on Windows 10 and it worked:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\me> wsl
me@me:/mnt/c/Users/me$ which code
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
me@me:/mnt/c/Users/me$ code
```

If necessary you could use the full path -- and set it to a shell variable -- to execute directly.